# Dependency Logs into constructor behave different than logs injected into functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I created the following function:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class DINotWorking
    {
        ILogger _log;
        public DINotWorking(ILogger<DINotWorking> log)
        {
            _log = log;
            _log.LogInformation("I can in constructor");
        }

        [FunctionName("HttpTrg1")]
        public IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,ILogger logger1)
        {
            _log.LogInformation("Contructor injected Log works !");
            logger1.LogInformation("Function injected log Work!");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string responseMessage = $"Hello, '{name}'. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

`host.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "FunctionApp1.DINotWorking": "Information",
      "FunctionApp1.DINotWorking.User": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

The function has two loggers available in it:

1. `_log` is a dependency injected class member with the type `ILogger<DINotWorking>`.
2. `logger1` is dependency injected function parameter with the type `ILogger`

I am going to reference them as **#1 and #2 going forward**.

They behave differently in different environments:

**local development - Azure Function tools**

In local development environment in azure function tools both #1 and #2 behave identical:

[image]

**Deployed - Azure Function portal - Application Insight**

In Azure Function portal, they both log to Application Insight. Means both #1 and #2 behave identical:

[image]

**Deployed - Azure Function portal - Filesystem Logs**

In Azure Function portal, #1 log entries do not show in the Filesystem logs. **Why?**

[image]

**Question: Why #1 log entries do not show in Filesystem logs?**

Azure function logging is a black box to me.

Obviously, there is a difference between constructor injected `ILogger` and Function injected `ILogger`.

Does this have anything to do with Log Categories [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-categories)

How can I see the difference in my code?

How can I make them behave the same in all environment in the `host.json`?

**Update #1**

Per @Hari Krishna suggestion, I've changed the `host.json` file to the following.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "FunctionApp1.HttpTrg1": "Information",
      "FunctionApp1.HttpTrg1.User": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is still persisting (outstanding).

How can I diagnose this issue? Is there anyway the hosting tells me why it is ignoring constructor injected log entries from file system logs?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK,

> In Azure Function portal, #1 log entries do not show in the Filesystem logs. **Why?**

By default, FileSystem Logs shows the Function execution logs like executing, executed, and error.

We can configure the `host.json` file to get all the logs (App Insights logs + File System Logs) in File System Logs because everything should be configured whatever the logs you want to push to Application Insights:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.HttpTrigger1": "Information",
      "default": "None"
    }
  }
}
```

I have configured the `fileLoggingMode` in `host.json` to log both (application & function). Then the output is:

**File System Logs**:

[image]

**App Insights Logs**:

[image]

For more information on `fileLoggingMode` attributes, refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging) and GitHub Open Informative [Ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59008).

#### Updated Answer:

Please Check that I have uploaded my code on my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/HariKrishna598/Azure-Functions-Custom-Logging-Project-01) by writing the similar code as yours and shown how to configure the `Host.json` as well as Function Code.

**Results**:

**Locally I can see both the logs**:

[image]

After deploying to Azure Function App, App Insights Logs were:

[image]

Also, the File System Logs were:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help. My host.json is identical to yours - different order, same setup. Do you know why my instance does not behave same as yours?

Comment: Before the `loglevel` attribute, use this "fileLoggingMode": "always", in the `host.json`

Comment: I do have "fileLoggingMode": "always". Are you suggesting the problem is with the order?

Comment: `DINotWorking` - Is this your Function Name that you have given in the `host.json` - `loglevel` code block? I believe `HttpTrg1` is your Function Name that you have to give in `host.json` - `loglevel` code block.

Comment: Oh DINotWorking is the class name . The C# type is FunctionApp1.DINotWorking. Do I need to use class name or function name?

Comment: FunctionName should be used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249435/discussion-between-allan-xu-and-hari-krishna).

Comment: please see my update #1, the issue still persisting. I wonder how to diagnose this.

Comment: After modifying the `host.json` file, have you deployed it again?

Comment: Hello @AllanXu, Could you please check the updated answer that I have provided the code with results which helps to resolve the issue.

Comment: The issue remains outstanding. I was hoping to find a technique to demystify the internal state of logging. I am working on a code that uses reflection, iterates in all MessageLoggers in the _logger and dumps all the properties. Once I finalize the idea, I will share here. If you built or know such code please share here.

Comment: Have you checked my shared code (Github Repos link) in the updated answer.

Comment: I did. Please consider that my challenge is not finding a code that works. My challenge is for find a way how to diagnose the problem when it is not working.

Comment: Please note that I reduced and simplified my project to the code I explained in the my question. The actual project running in production is much more complex and bigger. I really need to find a way to diagnose and find the root of my issue, when it is not working in one of the many deployments. This logging fragility is a big problem for me. I need to find a code that automatically detect the issue by analyzing the logger's internals and and states the problem.

Comment: The Function App -> Log Stream  shows the messages from loggers that were injected.
The function -> monitor (that also has filesystem logs) wont show the messages.
(Function App is not the same as function)